# Localization file not effective rendering a Razor page in MVC ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-2.2

My Razor page looks like this.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
<h1>@Localizer["Index"]</h1>
...
```

My *Startup.cs* contains the following.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
  services.AddLocalization(a => a.ResourcesPath = "/");

  services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(a =>
  {
    CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = {
      new CultureInfo("sv-SE"),
      new CultureInfo("se")
    };
    a.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("se");
    a.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    a.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
  });
  ...
}
```

I placed a file called *Controllers.HomeController.se.resx* directly in the project's root. The controller *HomeController* contains the injection.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  private readonly Context _context;
  private readonly IStringLocalizer<HomeController> _localizer;

  public HomeController(Context context, IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)
  {
    _context = context;
    _localizer = localizer;
  }
  ...
}
```

The application doesn't crash **but** the string renedered is *Index* and not the value from the RESX file. I've tried to follow [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2) as closely as possible but apparently I've missed something. I need help finding what that would be.

I breakpointed and checked the value of *_localizer["Index"]* in the constructor. As expected, the flag for the file not being found is set to *true*. Checking the value of *SearchedLocation* gives me *Web...Controllers.MemberController*. I can't tell if those three dots is the correct one for the RESX file in the project's root. I was expecting *se* somewhere in the name too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to place you resources files in root of the project you should set `ResourcesPath` as following

```
services.AddLocalization(a => a.ResourcesPath = ""); //empty string
```

With this settings `SearchedLocation` will give you `Web.Controllers.MemberController` which points to `Controllers.MemberController.resx` file in the root of the project.

To use localization in view you have to follow `Views.{ControllerName}.{ViewName}.resx` pattern. For example if you have `HomeController` and `About` view in it you need to have `Views.Home.About.resx` file to use localization.

Another convention resource reader follows when searching for localization files is searching the files in respective folders rather than by dot separated names. For example if `ResourcesPath` is set to `"Resources"` the following variants are equal

```
Resources.Views.Home.About.resx
Resources\Views.Home.About.resx
Resources\Views\Home.About.resx
Resources\Views\Home\About.resx
```

So it's possible to structure your localization files by folders.

And you didn't specify you added `app.UseRequestLocalization()` in your `Startup.cs`. If you don't do this your application won't be able to determine request culture and it will always point to default resource file. Read more [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#localization-middleware).

**Note**

There are 2 ways of configuring `RequestLocalizationOptions` for request localization, via `services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>` or passing constructed options object (or delegate) to `app.UseRequestLocalization`. Effectively there is no difference between these approaches, they are totally equal in terms of localization middleware. But if at any point of an application you need to get `RequestLocalizationOptions` you won't be able to get value passed to `app.UseRequestLocalization`. But it is easy to accompish with `services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>` (it's general approach described [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2))

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly RequestLocalizationOptions _requestLocalizationOptions;

    public HomeController(IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> options)
    {
        _requestLocalizationOptions = options.Value;
    }

    //..
}
```

Comment: Your bounty comes in 23 hours 59 minutes, mate. The site won't let me provide it already now. Sorry.

Comment: Now, what is the default resource file, if nothing else is specified? If I inject *IStringLocalization<Lang>*, will that point to *Lang.resx* with no language code?

Comment: @DonkeyBanana Nope, it will point to Lang.resx with language code corresponding to request culture. You can test different cultures by adding `?culture=sv-SE` in address bar

Comment: Your bounty has been awarded. I almost forgot. Good thing SO reminded. That being said, the question is answered, of course, but I wonder if you have a quick tip on a good approach to **switching** between the lingos. At the moment, I have the default languages set to *sv* and it works sufficiently. However, sooner or later, I'd like to advance and be able to choose the language. In the menu, I can add a switcher, so the GUI part isn't an issue. But the business logic of changing the RESX being used and storying the selected lingo etc. are areas where I fear I'm going to make poor choices.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana The easiest is using cookie localization. Create action accepting culture as string, create `RequestCulture` from it then set response cookie by making cookie value using  `CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue` and key `CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName`. When you set a cookie it will be used in subsequent requests so it will be "stored" so to speak. If you actually want to store user culture in datase then you need to implement own `RequestCultureProvider` to fetch culture from database by current user. Hope it helps.