# ASP.NET Core supported cultures not being returned by RequestLocalizationOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to learn asp.net core for the first time, and I'm having an issue with returning the currently supported cultures in the view (trying to implement a select element to switch languages). Following the [tutorial on msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2), 
I added the following to the `Configure` method in Startup.cs:

```
IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    new CultureInfo("en-CA"),
    new CultureInfo("fr-CA")
};
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-CA"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

In `ConfigureServices` I've added:

```
services.AddLocalization(o =>
{
    // We will put our translations in a folder called Resources
    o.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
});

services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation().AddViewLocalization();
```

I "know" (think?) localization is working, because when I hardcode the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` value, it picks up my resx strings.

However, now I would like to grab these cultures in the view, and dynamically build the select. I have something like this:

`var cultureItems = SupportedLocales.Value.SupportedUICultures.Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Text = x.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToUpper(), Value = x.Name});`

This enumerable is only 1 entry long (EN). In fact, setting the cultures doesn't seem to have any effect, as the only culture that shows up is the default culture, even if it's not in the list of supported cultures?

Reading [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5457) (unfortunately, the link that the solution points to is broken), I gathered that I have to register the RequestLocalizationOptions object with the DI, so I did this:

**Inside `ConfigureServices` method**

```
IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    new CultureInfo("en-CA"),
    new CultureInfo("fr-CA")
};

var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-CA"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
};
services.AddSingleton<RequestLocalizationOptions>(localizationOptions);
```

**start of the `Configure` method**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, RequestLocalizationOptions options)
{
    app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
```

Comment: Well you have a singleton in DI so why not inject that wherever you are building that select?

Comment: You're right, I was using @inject IOption<RequestLocalizationOptions> (copied from another tutorial). Getting rid of IOption fixed it.

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679466/localization-file-not-effective-rendering-a-razor-page-in-mvc-asp-net-core-2-2) and my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54696895/7775908)